# Can't hide soft keyboard in Android Studio project, why?

Tags: android, view, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to hide the soft keyboard in an Android Studio project. The View in the hideKeyboard() method keeps coming up as null... I can't figure out why... Please advise.

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rewashlog_options);

    luxuryCountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.luxuryCountTextView);
    fullCountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fullCountTextView);
    quickCountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quickCountTextView);
    totalCountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalCountTextView);
    emailRecipient = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailRecipient);

    instantiateMonthSpinner();
    instantiateYearSpinner();
    getEntireRewashList();
    updateListView();
    hideKeyboard();

}

 private void hideKeyboard() {
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: try hiding it using handler.post(). You are now trying to hide it before it is shown

Comment: Try `yourEditText.getWindowToken()` instead of view.getWindowToken(). I think here it is emailRecipient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in your mainfest to hide the keyboard on activity launch like this

```
`<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

In my case it works.

Answer (score 0):

Update your InputMethodManager :

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```